# PCA for KNN: preprocess parameter in caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, knn, feature-selection

I am conducting `knn` regression on my data, and would like to:

a) cross-validate through repeatedcv to find an optimal `k`;

b) when building `knn` model, using `PCA` at 90% level threshold to reduce dimensionality.

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
data = cbind(rnorm(15, 100, 10), matrix(rnorm(300, 10, 5), ncol = 20)) %>% 
  data.frame()

colnames(data) = c('True', paste0('Day',1:20))
tr = data[1:10, ] #training set
tt = data[11:15,] #test set

train.control = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=3)
k = train(True ~ .,
          method     = "knn",
          tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:10),
          trControl  = train.control, 
          preProcess = c('scale','pca'),
          metric     = "RMSE",
          data       = tr)
```

My question is: currently the PCA threshold is by default 95% (not sure), how can I change it to 80%?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to use  `method="adaptive_cv"` where you can set `alpha` within `adaptive=list(min=5, alpha=0.20, method="gls", complete=TRUE)`?

Comment: Jay, thank you for your advice! It seems that you suggested me to change cross-validation parameters, however, would it be possible to change the option for `pca`?

Comment: I saw this link https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46256/244949 and this solution seems working. For instance, `tc = trainControl(method = "cv", preProcOptions = list(thresh=0.8))`, then in the `knn` model, ` train(y, method="knn", trControl = tc, preProcess= c("scale", "center", "pca"))`. Do you think this will mix up the parameters since have three `preProcess` options?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add preProcOptions argument in trainControl

```
train.control = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=3, preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.80))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.